# Replace html table layout with divs when content overflows browser window

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

Using tables for html layout has been discouraged for some time. I am creating a web page that has rows of varying numbers of elements. Each row should be centred based on the width of the widest row. I can do this with a table as shown below.

I have tried replacing this with divs and it works as long as the widest row is not wider than the browser window. How can I get the div version to work the same as the table version in this situation? Thank you.

**Table version**

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
  div.box {
      display: inline-block;
      width:300px;
      height:100px;
      margin:10px;
  }
  div.red {
      background:red;
  }
  div.green {
      background:green;
  }
  td.oneline {
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-align: center;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='oneline'>
        <div class='box green'></div>
        <div class='box green'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='oneline'>
        <div class='box red'></div>
        <div class='box red'></div>
        <div class='box red'></div>
        <div class='box green'></div>
        <div class='box green'></div>
        <div class='box red'></div>
        <div class='box red'></div>
        <div class='box red'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Div version**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div.box {
      display: inline-block;
      width:300px;
      height:100px;
      margin:10px;
  }
  div.red {
      background:red;
  }
  div.green {
      background:green;
  }
  div.container {
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-align: center;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is not a table (table-layout) , it won't shrink/expand to fit its content.

2 options:

- set `display:table;` to `.container`
- set `width:max-content` to `.container` ;

both rules (one or the other) will allow the container to be wider than the viewport's width or its block parent.

demo with width:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div.box {
      display: inline-block;
      width:300px;
      height:100px;
      margin:10px;
  }
  div.red {
      background:red;
  }
  div.green {
      background:green;
  }
  div.container {
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-align: center;
      width:max-content;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

demo with display

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div.box {
      display: inline-block;
      width:300px;
      height:100px;
      margin:10px;
  }
  div.red {
      background:red;
  }
  div.green {
      background:green;
  }
  div.container {
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-align: center;
      display:table;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
      <div class='box green'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
      <div class='box red'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

both rule implies different behavior, look for the one closest to your needs.